# How to fill rows automatically in pandas, from the content found in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python3 and pandas have a dataframe with dozens of columns and lines about food characteristics. Below is a summary:

```
alimentos = pd.read_csv("alimentos.csv",sep=',',encoding = 'utf-8')
alimentos.reset_index()
index   alimento    calorias
0   0   iogurte     40
1   1   sardinha    30
2   2   manteiga    50
3   3   maçã        10
4   4   milho       10
```

The column "alimento" (food) has the lines "iogurte", "sardinha", "manteiga", "maçã" and "milho", which are food names.

I need to create a new column in this dataframe, which will tell what kind of food is. I gave the name "classificacao"

```
alimentos['classificacao'] = ""
alimentos.reset_index()
index   alimento    calorias    classificacao
0   0   iogurte     40  
1   1   sardinha    30  
2   2   manteiga    50  
3   3   maçã        10  
4   4   milho       10
```

Depending on the content found in the "alimento" column I want to automatically fill the rows of the "classificacao" column

For example, when finding "iogurte" fill -> "laticinio". When find "sardinha" -> "peixe". By finding "manteiga" -> "gordura animal". When finding "maçã" -> "fruta". And by finding "milho" -> "cereal"

Please, is there a way to automatically fill the rows when I find these strings?

Comment: It seems you need `map` like `df['classificacao'] = df['alimento'].map({"iogurte" : "laticinio", "sardinha": "peixe", ...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a mapping of *all* the possible values in the "alimento" column, you can just create a dictionary and use `.map(d)`, as shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'alimento': ['iogurte','sardinha', 'manteiga', 'maçã', 'milho'],  
                   'calorias':range(10,60,10)})

d = {"iogurte":"laticinio", "sardinha":"peixe", "manteiga":"gordura animal", "maçã":"fruta", "milho": "cereal"}

df['classificacao'] = df['alimento'].map(d)
```

However, in real life often we can't map everything in a dict (because of outliers that occur once in a blue moon, faulty inputs, etc.), and in which case the above would return `NaN` in the "classificacao" column. This could cause some issues, so think about setting a default value, like "Other" or "Unknown". To to that, just append `.fillna("Other")` after `map(d)`.